# Nested `include()` directives - How to include a file (which includes another) from more than one directories?

Tags: path, include, php, include-path

I have these three files to work with:

`document_root/include/config.php`
`document_root/include/database.php`
`document_root/index.php`

And the relevant part of the file contents are like below:

**config.php**

```
// ...
$MyVar = 100;
// ...
```

**database.php**

```
// ...
require('config.php');
// Aiming to use the definitions in "config.php" here
// ...
```

**index.php**

```
// ...
require('include/database.php');
// Using the code in "database.php" here
// ...
```

The problem is that, `config.php` is somehow not included, and yet no error message is given (in E_ALL mode). I can't access to the definitions in the `config.php` file from `database.php` file while running the code in `index.php`.

In my `PHP.ini` file `include_path` is set to `C:\...\document_root\include` directory.
An PHP version is 5.3.0.

I have observed that, if I change the `require()` directive in `database.php` as
`require('include/config.php');`
the code runs without any failure and everything is just fine. But this solution is not possible in practice, because I'm planing to include the `config.php` file from multiple locations.

What is the cause of this problem?
How can I fix it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this problem is, that `include` resolves relative filenames based on the *working directory*, not based on the directory where the file is located that does the `include`.

The working directory is the directory of the PHP file that is launched by the webserver (in your case `index.php` I guess). If that file includes some other file, the working directory is not changed. It can be changed manually using [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php), but you should not do that solely for the sake of an `include`.

One possible solution is to use

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '[RELATIVE_PATH]';
```

where `[RELATIVE_PATH]` is the relative path from the file that does the include to the file that is included.

In PHP 5.3, `__DIR__` can be used instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Your answer is good and working, thanks very much.
But I want to learn the reason why do I have to specify a path when including a file, even though already being specified its path in the `PHP.ini` directive `include_path`?
Why doesn't this general setting apply here?

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused myself. The [documentation for include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) says "... **include()** will finally check in the calling script's own directory ...", meaning you should not have had a problem in the first place. I am sure the quoted part wasn't there the last time I checked.